# VBA Quickly find and delete rows if column value=""

Tags: excel, vba, performance, delete-row

I created a macro to in order to generate a daily report. However it takes a very long time to run. The portion of the macro that finds a value in column AN and deletes the entire row, takes minuets to run.

The following example deletes all the rows that do not contain the value "CAT" in column AN.

Is there a more efficient way to write the code so it does not take so long to run? Possibly add an array for additional values as well? (CAT, DOG, COW) 
Thanks!

Code lacking efficiency (working, but with long run time due to hundreds of rows):

```
'False screen updating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'deleting all other types other than CAT from "samples" tab (excluding the header row, row 1)
Sheets("sample").Select
LastRowNum = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
ReadRow = 2
For n = 2 To LastRowNum
    If Range("AN" & ReadRow).Value <> "CAT" Then
    Range("AN" & ReadRow).EntireRow.Delete
Else
  ReadRow = ReadRow + 1
End If
```

Comment: turn off AutoCalculation and screen updating

Comment: The whole `For n = 2 To LastRowNum` loop is pretty wrong.

Comment: @user10862412 I am not sure why n = 2 is in the code, since n is not a declared variable. I found some of this code online and it did the job so I did not change any of the code.

Comment: @ArcherBird I added "Application.ScreenUpdating = False", however it still takes a long time to checking 4000 rows. Is there a way to add any array to preform the loop more efficiency?

Answer (score 3):

Use Union and delete once:

```
With Worksheets("sample")
    Dim LastRowNum As Long
    LastRowNum = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim rng As Range

    Dim n As Long
    For n = 2 To LastRowNum
        If .Range("AN" & n).Value <> "CAT" Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = .Rows(n)
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, .Rows(n))
            End If
        End If
    Next n

    rng.EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that will remove blank rows, should be fairly quick.

```
Public Sub RemoveBlankRows(ws As Worksheet)
On Error GoTo errorHandler:

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then ws.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Exit Sub

errorHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub ExampleUsage()
     RemoveBlankRows ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
End Sub
```

Comment: if there are lots of formulas in the workbook, you should also add a `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` in there too

Comment: A good optimization to be sure, see the edit